# new rails 4.2 app still shows gem 'rails', '4.0.3'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now my rails version is 4.03.

jonstark@jonstark-pc:~/rails_projects$ rails --version
    Rails 4.0.3

To make a new project I use this command:

```
jonstark@jonstark-pc:~/rails_projects/optima$ rails _4.2_ new optima
```

But in my optima project Gemfile I have:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
```

I can of course change it manually to 4.2 then run bundle update, but what do I do to automate all of this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is you are trying to create a new project with rails version 4.2 but your rails version is 4.0.3. Soeither way you can create specific Gemset for your new projects and for your existing one's also.
just do `jonstark@jonstark-pc:~/rails_projects/optima$ rvm gemset create your_gemset_name` and then `rvm gemset use your_gemset_name`then do `gem install bundler` and `gem install rails` of your choice.

Comment: may be I can simply update rails version to 4.2? this seems better than creating a cpecific gameset

Comment: Yea you can but creating Specific Gemsets for Specific projects have it's own benefits e.g:- lets say now you install rails 4.2 for a project ok and later you want to work on a project with rails version 4.0 or maybe 3 then you will again do a new rails installation and then bundle install and then chances are that that bundle install will install rails 3 specific versions for every Rails dependencies say activejob, action mailer. ., So to avoid that mess Gemsets are a better preferred way.

Comment: Hope you got me(with my poor grammar) what i'm tryin to make you understand.

Comment: Okay can you give me an example of your gem set? cause I am afraid that my current gemfile is horibly outdated

Comment: jonstark@jonstark-pc:~/rails_projects/your_project$ rvm gemset create any_name
jonstark@jonstark-pc:~/rails_projects/your_project$ rvm gemset use any_name

thats' it not matter whether your gemfile is outdated or what so ever and if it is outdated then it will help you to prevent conflicting of gems dependencies in your future updated projects.
If it solved your query then mark answer as accepted.